# "close to within" vs "close in to within"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, word-usage

Which sentence is correct in this context?

..."missiles fired by pirates too cowardly to **close** to within turret range!"
versus
..."missiles fired by pirates too cowardly to **close in** to within turret range!"

Current complete sentence is:

> If it seems pointless to you to sacrifice the firepower of an entire turret just for limited protection against missiles, you may think differently the next time you find your ship being bombarded by missiles fired by pirates too cowardly to close to within turret range!

Thank you

Comment: It sounds more natural to me to say "to come within turret range."

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need "close" as your verb? It's one of those multiple-meaning words that require context to parse. I found both sentences required me to read the end twice to get what was meant. (Yes, I'm a native speaker.) I think @TonyDiRienzo was on the mark suggesting "come within turret range." It's unambiguous on the first reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The former is (subjectively?) better, the latter is still fine, though I assume your "to" and "turrent" are typos.